# I want get_posts to return only posts of logged in user

Tags: wordpress

Here's my code:

I'd like to only return posts of logged in user.

I am populating a dropdown form in WordPress gravity forms.

```
$current_user = _wp_get_current_user(); 
function populate_posts( $form) {
   foreach ( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
       if ( $field->type != 'select' || strpos( $field->cssClass, 'populate-posts' ) === false ) {
         continue;
       }
       $posts = get_posts( 'post_type=credit cards&numberposts=-1&post_status=publish&author=$current_user' );
       $choices = array();
       foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
         $choices[] = array( 'text' => $post->post_title, 'value' => $post->post_title );
       }
       $field->placeholder = 'Select Credit Card';
       $field->choices = $choices;
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

As i understand question of your's is to get "Post of Current User".Then here is a below code of it.

1) You need to pass author ID(Current User ID) as argument.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
$args = array(
'author'        =>  $current_user->ID,
'orderby'       =>  'post_date',
'order'         =>  'ASC',
);
```

2) Pass above argument is post as below :

```
$current_user_posts = get_posts( $args );
```

I Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use WP_Query()

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$query_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'author' => $user->ID,
);
$query = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post();
        $post = $query->post;
        echo $post->post_title;
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
else{
    echo 'No posts found.';
}
```